# Globals, classes and Parallel Python

Tags: python, class, global, parallel-python

I have been reading for a few hours on how globals=globals() works on Parallel Python, and I am still a little bit confused, maybe you can help me... I am writing a code which can basically be summarized as:

```
import pp

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.h = 2

def f():
    foo = Foo()
    return foo.h

ppservers = ()
job_server = pp.Server(ppservers=ppservers)
#print globals()
g = job_server.submit(f, (), globals = globals())
r = g()
```

The output is "global name 'Foo' is not defined", as a few others have encountered before me... I know that the globals argument is used to transfer functions and classes to the server in a simplified way, so I hoped that it had passed the Foo() class, as it is in the global variables before executing the job_server.submit instruction (as you can see by de-commenting the print globals() instruction).

What am I missing about PP that I should know? Is there a way to make this code run without too many changes?

Thanks for reading me, I hope that some of you get how this works!

(Remark: I do not want to create an instance of Foo outside of the parallelized jobs, simply because initializing an instance triggers the whole program, which is within the **init**(self) function... bad idea, I know...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue revolving around being able to have `pp` track down and associate the code dependencies correctly. `pp` inspects the first object passed in to `submit` (i.e. `f`), and extracts the source code… which it then passes to the other processes. It also passes in any additional objects that are passed in `globals`.  However, `pp` primarily tracks functions, classes, and modules -- it has trouble with instances and many other objects.

If you use a fork of `pp` called `ppft` (it imports as `pp`), it should work as expected.  `ppft` uses a better code inspection package (`dill.source` from `dill`), to extract the source code from a broader range of python objects and more complex dependencies.

```
>>> import pp
>>> class Foo(object):
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.h = 2
... 
>>> def f():
...   foo = Foo()
...   return foo.h
... 
>>> ppservers = ()
>>> job_server = pp.Server(ppservers=ppservers)
>>> g = job_server.submit(f, (), globals=globals())
>>> r = g()
>>> r
2
```

Get `ppft` here: https://github.com/uqfoundation

It's also `pip` installable.